# Symfony2 - By default default route parameter is set, work but is not displayed

Tags: symfony, redirect, twig

I set a `defaults` value for my route so the route has a default value and my action works fine but the default value is not displayed in the URL. I try to redirect to the root like below :

```
if ($value == "TheValueRequired")
{
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("the_right_route", array(
        'value' => $value,
    )));
}
```

It works but then I loose the array that contains the variables for the rendering of the twig template.

Comment: You render nothing in this case. You just "call" another route with some parameter.

Comment: Thank you @scoolnico but so how I should proceed?

Comment: Do you need to render a specific template if your condition is true?

Answer (score 0):

A small example of what you could have in your controller if your goal is to display `value` in the view:

```
/.../

if ($value == "TheValueRequired") {

    return $this->render('template.html.twig', ['value' => $value]);

}

/.../
```

Comment: To be more precise: I got a form and when it successfuly submit the action attribute go to my desired Route and then the declaration of this same Route got a default value for the Route parameter, and everything is working fine. Except that my url is : localhost/myRoute/
My goal is to obtain : localhost/myRoute/myDefaultRouteParameter.

Comment: In the form if I do action="{{ path('name_of_my_route }}/myDefaultRouteParameter", I got what I want, it displayed, but if I access "/" (webroot), I still landed on localhost/myRoute/ with the none displayed default route value that working fine